# performance question running mysql timediff on each page load

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run timediff between the time now and the last modified stamp of a value.
Depending if it were under or over 60 minutes I would show a button to allow the value to be changed.

Is this a no-no because of database performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timediff` cannot cause any performance issues, but fetching rows, that used to perform such calculaton - can. So it all depends on what your query does.